# Jpa pojo and relation mapping in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

Currently  I have a pojo

```
class Myclass{
    private int taskid;
    private String tasktype;
    private int Monitory_by;
    private int Assigned_by;
    private int Report_to;
    private int Assigned_to;
}
```

where Monitory_by ,Assigned_by, Report_to,Assigned_to are primary key values of users so I have pojo for users which gives all the data of users.

The point is to relate this to pojo where  **Monitory_by,Assigned_by fields are optional** (i.e., the values may be given or not). please help me

Comment: I tuned the subject to mention hibernate.  I assume that's right?

Comment: Can you include the mapping configurations that you have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the tags you have used I am assuming that you are using Hibernate with JPA.  I suggest going over the extensive documentation Hibernate provides on [entity mapping](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html).  This reference includes help on primary key mapping (Ids) and foreign key (one-to-many) mappings.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Integer` instead of `int`, it's nullable.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to use primitive types to mark relationship with another entity?

In JPA world you typically use entity types instead of straight primary keys. So instead of `int Assigned_to` you'd have `User assignedTo`.

If so, than you could define optionality of the relationship by using `optional` attribute of one of relationship annotations like `@OneToMany`, `@OneToOne`, `@ManyToOne` or `@ManyToMany`, so it would be i.e.:

```
@OneToOne(optional = true)
private User assignedTo;
```

PS. By default all relationships are optional, so setting `optional = true` is not required.

Comment: Thanks, i am new buddy to jpa  so can you provide some resource(links or ref ) on this concept

Comment: Sure, Sri Sankaran posted one resource in his answer and I think it's really worth reading. I'm taking about Hibernate documentation about [entities mapping](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html).